# The disposal of unnecessary data in a data set, filtering or filtration?

Tags: word-choice

Which is the most fitting word for the disposal of unnecessary data in a data set; *filtering* or *filtration*?

e.g. *Log data filtering* or *Log data filtration*?

Comment: I'd use  "to screen data", with the "for unnecessary data" implied if you want to put the emphasis on the removed part (as in "screen people for disease")--> data screening. Or " to filter data" if you want to highlight the set kept-->data filtering

Comment: If you do a Google ngram search for `(data filtering),(data filtration)` you will see that *data filtering* is far more common, and that *data filtration* usually appears in texts that were authored probably by non-native speakers (judging by their names).

Comment: Thanks for your answers. One example: is 
"A proper _filtering_ algorithm will save valuable information and discard the rest" preferred over 
"A proper _filtration_ algorithm will save valuable information and discard the rest"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Filtration* is [the process of separating solid/particles from fluids](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filtration).

I would then go with filtering, though [*filter*](http://ui-patterns.com/patterns/TableFilter) alone may do as well.